# Display Image title and Image description in Easy FancyBox image popup

Tags: wordpress, image, popup, fancybox, caption

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-fancybox/ plugin works good for me.

I want to display image Title and image Description inside popup box. I review all settings. But can’t find solutions for this.

Review this screen shot for my requirements -> http://nimb.ws/C27FvH

So please help me.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Comment: Which version you are using for Easy- fancybox , because current version is providing a way to displayed title. please check https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/

Comment: I am using latest version but Title and Description both now display.

Comment: Didn't get you is it working or not ?

Comment: It's not working.